# python: Reorder list of strings first numerically, than alphabetically

Tags: python

I am beginner in python lists. I have a list of feature classes named by type and year of occurrence: feature class "a_05" occurred in 2005, feature class "b_03" occurred in 2003.

I would like to sort the items in a list increasingly by time they occurred (2003, 2005...), and if two types occurred in the same year, than they should be ordered alphabetically.

Let's say, list

```
fcs = [u'b_02', u'a_05', u'a_03', u'b_03']
```

should **results** in `[ u'b_02', u'a_03', u'b_03', u'a_05']`,

i.e. first years `(_02,_03,_03,_05)` and then alphabetically `u'a_03', u'b_03'`.

Using simply `fcs.sort()` my items are instead first sorted alphabetically, than by numbers: `[u'a_03', u'a_05', u'b_02', u'b_03']`

**How can I alter my item names to be able to sort them first by numbers, not by the letters?**

Comment: `print(sorted(fcs, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1])))`

Comment: Just to help out, there are some great examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) that describe all _sorts_ of different ways to `sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fcs = [u'b_02', u'a_05', u'a_03', u'b_03']
fcs.sort(key=lambda x:[int(x.split('_')[1]),x.split('_')[0]])
```

output

```
['b_02', 'a_03', 'b_03', 'a_05']
```

full documentation for using lambda [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

here  i am making an order to sort, sort  list with method 1 and if in method 1 got few value which are same then sort those same values with the method 2 (it's like nested sorting). order to sort is defined in a list.

method 1 : x.split('_')[1]] # on bases of integer

method 2 : x.split('_')[0]] # on bases of alphabets

PS. sorry i am bad at explaining stuff.

Comment: can you please some dummy explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sorted` with a custom key.

**Ex:**

```
fcs = [u'b_02', u'a_05', u'a_03', u'b_03']
print(sorted(fcs, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1])))
```

or `sort`

**Ex:**

```
fcs = [u'b_02', u'a_05', u'a_03', u'b_03']
fcs.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1]))
print(fcs)
```

**Output:**

```
['b_02', 'a_03', 'b_03', 'a_05']
```

Using the `lambda` function to split the element by `_` and then converting it to `int`

Comment: thank you so much! can you please a little explanation as well? it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of simple comparisons you can use `key` argument with lambda function that defines what exactly you want to compare (you can see it in the another answer). But sometimes you will lack the `key` argument. In this case you can use [cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) function from the `functools` module. It allows you to do complicated comparisons inside the function, wrap it with this function and send to `sorted()` function as `key` argument. Here is the example:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

fcs = [u'b_02', u'a_05', u'a_03', u'b_03']

def waka(s1, s2):
    name1, year1 = s1.rsplit('_', 1)
    name2, year2 = s2.rsplit('_', 1)
    if year1 > year2:
        return 1
    elif year1 < year2:
        return -1
    elif name1 > name2:
        return 1
    elif name1 < name2:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

sorted(fcs, key=cmp_to_key(waka))


['b_02', 'a_03', 'b_03', 'a_05']
```